# How can I properly annotate types using flask_sqlalchemy?

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, mypy, python-typing

I have a working Flask application which uses SQLAlchemy / `flask_sqlalchemy`. To give you an impression, I've created a super stripped down version (`apps.py` and `models.py`). The application works. The issue is that `mypy` complains about the usage of `db.Model` within `models.py`:

```
error: Name 'db.Model' is not defined
```

The reason is likely that this is created when `db.init_app(app)` is called. How can I fix this? Is there a better option than ignoring it?

```
# type: ignore
```

### app.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="templates")
    db.init_app(app)
    return app
```

### models.py

```
from app import db

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    username = db.Column(db.String, unique=True)
```

Comment: I could not reproduce the error. I used mypy 0.660 and python 3.6. Can you please provide version information? Thanks!

Comment: @above_c_level I can't reproduce the error with the minimal example either ... interesting. I still get it in my real codebase. I try to adjust the example

Comment: Is it the whole `app.py` file? You are not even trying to run it when the error occurs?(`app.run()`) By the way using app in a function is less comfortable you really shouldn't do it.... Try to put `db` and `app` as global vars so you'd be able to do `db = SQLAlchemy(app)`

Comment: @above_c_level I've created an example where one can see the issue: https://github.com/MartinThoma/algorithms/tree/master/medium/flask-testing/example-app

Comment: I'm not sure why it appears in this folder and not in the code I have above.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no progress with this on the official library. There's a PR with some work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62794599/how-can-i-properly-annotate-types-using-flask-sqlalchemy but it was closed. I'll try to figure it out a way to add typing since I have a project built with the same library.

Answer (score 3):

You need https://pypi.org/project/sqlalchemy-stubs/

quote from https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/declarative/basic_use.html

> Using MyPy with SQLAlchemy models
>
> If you are using PEP 484 static type checkers for Python,
> a MyPy plugin is included with [type stubs for SQLAlchemy](https://github.com/dropbox/sqlalchemy-stubs).
> The plugin is tailored towards SQLAlchemy declarative models.

Comment: Note there is now [sqlalchemy2-stubs](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy2-stubs) which replaces sqlalchemy-stubs.

Answer (score -2):

Since you are using flask_sqlalchemy, Have you tried this,

*models.py*

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////tmp/test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    username = db.Column(db.String, unique=True)
```

**EDIT**
This is how my *app.py* looks like

```
from .settings import ProdConfig


def create_app(config_object=ProdConfig):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_object)
    register_blueprints(app)
    return app
```

Comment: Is there anything more than having `app` defined within `modes.py` instead of within `app.py`? This causes a lot of other issues.